# Questions about working with machine language

Tags: assembly, programming-languages, machine-code

I have a few questions about machine language:

1. How to write machine language code? And is this actually done?
2. What part of the architecture processes the machine language? (intel or amd chips? something else?)
3. Does each machine have a different machine language?

Thanks in advance for answers :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing English isn't your first language. I'll take my best guess at what you meant and keep my language simple.

1. Not usually possible. Assembly is the closest thing that is well supported.
2. The processor takes the machine code (intel, amd, etc.)
3. Different processors have different machine code.

Comment: yes my first language isn't English. But my answers are very clear.
Thanks for answer..

Comment: +1 - Nice answer but especially for taking the time to read and deal with the english-not-the-first-language issues.

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading these two Wikipedia articles:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language

They come in many different translations and will answer your questions nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're finding the same answer as me. I just started to learn machine language and want to see how it works.

I've write 2 articles about this and I hope it's useful to you.
http://pengwenqiang.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/machine-language-first-try-hanging-bootloader/
http://pengwenqiang.wordpress.com/2014/01/03/machine-language-second-try-print-a-character-bootloader/

The original idea came from http://viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php. And I just tried his method in a machine-language way.

The main idea is through writing several very simple x86 instructions in a boot sector (the first 512 bytes) of a bootable device to figure how instructions are processed by CPU.